# Two loops mixed up

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, loops

I have this code, I have removed some code that has nothing to do with my problem.

```
while ($row_pl = mysql_fetch_array($res_pl))
{
    // Uurtarief
    $sql_uur = "SELECT
                aantal_kop,
                tarief_min,
                tarief_max,
                tijd_min,
                tijd_max,
                tijd_extra
                FROM uurtarief
                WHERE machine = '".$row_pl['machine']."'
                ORDER BY aantal_kop ASC";

    if(!$res_uur = mysql_query($sql_uur))
    {
        include('includes/errors/database_error.php');
    }
    else
    {
        while ($row_uur = mysql_fetch_array($res_uur))
        {
            ?>
                <input type="text" name="tar_kop[]" size="8" value="<?php echo $row_uur['aantal_kop']; ?>" />
                <input type="text" name="tar_tarief[]" size="8" value="<?php echo $uurtarief; ?>" />
                <input type="text" name="tar_tijd_extra[]" size="8" value="<?php echo $row_uur['tijd_extra']; ?>" />
                <br />
            <?php
        }
    }

    ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="pl_aantal_kop[]" size="3" onChange="uur_tarief(this, <?php echo $i ?>)" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="pl_tarief_ph[]" size="4" value="" />
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

With javascript I'm trying to find the value in `pl_aantal_kop[]` and send the corresponding parameter to `pl_tarief_ph[]`

```
function uur_tarief(selectVeld, nr)
{
    if(document.getElementsByName('pl_aantal_kop[]')[nr].value == 1)
    {
        document.getElementsByName('pl_tarief_ph[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tarief[]')[0].value;
        document.getElementsByName('pl_snijtijd_extra[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tijd_extra[]')[0].value;
    }

    if(document.getElementsByName('pl_aantal_kop[]')[nr].value == 2)
    {
        document.getElementsByName('pl_tarief_ph[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tarief[]')[1].value;
        document.getElementsByName('pl_snijtijd_extra[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tijd_extra[]')[1].value;
    }

    if(document.getElementsByName('pl_aantal_kop[]')[nr].value == 3)
    {
        document.getElementsByName('pl_tarief_ph[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tarief[]')[2].value;
        document.getElementsByName('pl_snijtijd_extra[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tijd_extra[]')[2].value;
    }

    if(document.getElementsByName('pl_aantal_kop[]')[nr].value == 4)
    {
        document.getElementsByName('pl_tarief_ph[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tarief[]')[3].value;
        document.getElementsByName('pl_snijtijd_extra[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tijd_extra[]')[3].value;
    }

    if(document.getElementsByName('pl_aantal_kop[]')[nr].value == 5)
    {
        document.getElementsByName('pl_tarief_ph[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tarief[]')[4].value;
        document.getElementsByName('pl_snijtijd_extra[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tijd_extra[]')[4].value;
    }

    if(document.getElementsByName('pl_aantal_kop[]')[nr].value == 6)
    {
        document.getElementsByName('pl_tarief_ph[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tarief[]')[5].value;
        document.getElementsByName('pl_snijtijd_extra[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tijd_extra[]')[5].value;
    }
}
```

The problem that occurred is that the javascript keeps starting counting at the first line of the `while ($row_uur = mysql_fetch_array($res_uur))` loop instead of the field that belongs to the first loop. Below an screenshot of this loop.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can condense your JS to this:

```
function uur_tarief(selectVeld, nr)
{
    var index = document.getElementsByName('pl_aantal_kop[]')[nr].value;

    document.getElementsByName('pl_tarief_ph[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tarief[]')[index - 1].value;
    document.getElementsByName('pl_snijtijd_extra[]')[nr].value = document.getElementsByName('tar_tijd_extra[]')[index - 1].value;
}
```

Can you try this code and post back? Where are you initializing and calling the JavaScript code? The code you posted looks fine (although bloated severely), so it might be an issue elsewhere.

Comment: What about the value == 1, value == 2 etc. statements? They are part of the code. They are numbers that can be chosen of the the column as posted in the image.

Comment: Your value is always one greater than the index number, hence the `[index - 1]`.